# Ajv return valid schema if schema has required set and data is empty string

Tags: ajv

Hi I have just started to learn AJV and I am a bit confused on how it handles required fields. I am working on an already built project and maybe some of the configuration is not needed for the current use case, or is done wrong.

I am using AJV verion 5.5.1.

Here is my code:

```
    const opt = {
      $data: true, allErrors: true, verbose: true, unknownFormats: ['int32', 'int64', 'double']
    };
    opt['v5'] = true;
    const validator = withKeywords(new Ajv(opt), ['switch', 'if']);
    withError(this.validator);`enter code here`

    const schema = {
        'required': [
          'name'
        ],
        'type': 'object',
        'properties': {
          'name': {
            'type': 'string'
          }
        }
      }

     const data = {
        name: ''
     }

     const isValid = validator.validate(schema, data);
```

Now this will set the isValid variable to true and validator.errors has no errors which kind of confuses me a bit. Since what i hoped would happen was it to be false because at the schema level I am setting in the required property the 'name' key.

I also tryed setting data.name = null an I am getting isValid false with error that makes sense to me because I am setting the type to string at the schema level, but it is not a validation required error. I want be able to diferentiate beetween a required error and a type error.

How can I make the validator return false if a property does not have a value?